# Trying to multiply/divide the user input in Java using while loop, Integer.parseInt etc

Tags: java, string, while-loop, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator. I'm trying to change the user's input from string to int using Integer.parseInt.

PROBLEMS:

1- Even when I try to subtract the numbers, they are added together.

2- Multiplication and division don't even work. 
Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    print("Enter an arithmetic expression: " );
    String expression = readString();

    int num1;
    int num2;
    char operator;
    int i = 0; 

    while ( expression.charAt(0) != '0') {

        do { 
            i++;            
        } while ( Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(i)));

        num1 = Integer.parseInt(expression.substring(0,i));
        operator = expression.charAt(i);
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(expression.substring(i));

        int result;

        switch (operator) {

        case '+' : result = num1 + num2; break;
        case '-' : result = num1 - num2; break;
        case '*' : result = num1 * num2; break;
        case '/' : result = num1 / num2; break;

        default: result = - 1;

        }

        println ("The result is: " + result);
        print("Enter an arithmetic expression: " );
        expression = readString();
        i=0;

        }
    println("The program is terminated. Bye");
}
```

Comment: Try printing out your variables with `System.out.println` instead of actually doing operations. I suspect you'll find your issue pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

*Printing the intermediate values, or using a debugger, would have given you the answer, but here it is anyway.*

You mean:

```
num2 = Integer.parseInt(expression.substring(i + 1));
```

Otherwise input of `123-12` is:

```
num1 = Integer.parseInt(expression.substring(0,i)); // "123"
operator = expression.charAt(i);                    // '-'
num2 = Integer.parseInt(expression.substring(i));   // "-12"
```

And `123 - -12 = 123 + 12 = 135`.